# what pointer magic is this

Tags: c, pointers, casting, dereference

I am learning `C`. I am starting to understand pointers and type casting. I am following along with some guides and examples and I ran across this declaration:

```
uint32_t *sp;
...
*(uint32_t*)sp = (uint32_t)somevalue;
```

What is happening here? The first asterisk specifically is a mystery to me.

Comment: The first cast is redundant. Probably the second too, if it is some positive integer.

Comment: The cast to `uint32_t*` is unnecessary, since that is the same type as `sp` already, so the code is equivalent to `*sp = (uint32_t)somevalue;` (which makes it look less magical).

Comment: Apparenty the author hates his compiler and prefers to go without automatic type-checking. IOW: Read other code for learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breaking it down:

```
*(uint32_t*)sp
```

basically says to treat `sp` as a pointer to `uint32_t` (`(uint32_t *)` is a *cast expression*), and to dereference the result.

So,

```
*(uint32_t*)sp = (uint32_t)somevalue;
```

means, "take `somevalue`, convert it to type `uint32_t`, and store the result to the thing `sp` points to, and treat that thing as though it were also a `uint32_t`."

Note that the cast on `sp` is redundant; you've *already* declared it as a pointer to `uint32_t`, so that assignment could be written as

```
*sp = (uint32_t) somevalue;
```

Answer (score 2):

The first asterisk dereferences the `sp` pointer in order to assign the value of `somevalue` to the pointee.

I wonder why the cast, since this

```
*sp = (uint32_t) somevalue;
```

if `sp` is of type `uint32_t *` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The first asterisk is the [indirection operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator).

It is basically to get/access the *value* at the address held by the pointer.

Quoting the `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.3.2, *Address and indirection operators*

> The operand of the unary `*` operator shall have pointer type.

and

> The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is
>   a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the
>   object. [...]

Answer (score 0):

The first star dereferences `sp` after it had been cast to a pointer to a `uint32_t`, so that `somevalue` is written to that location.

However, the cast is unnecessary since `sp` is already a pointer to a `uint32_t`.  Furthermore, if `somevalue` is a numeric type, the cast on the right hand side is unnecessary too since the rvalue will be implicitly cast to the type of the lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion stems from the fact that this is not a declaration but in fact an assignment statement:

```
/* This is the declaration of sp as a pointer to uint32_t */
uint32_t *sp;

/* This is an assignment statement setting *sp to somevalue */
*(uint32_t*)sp = (uint32_t) somevalue;
```

It looks confusingly like a declaration because of the unnecessary casting of the lvalue which makes it sort of look like it's declaring the type.